# How large can integers be in Javascript before roundoff error?

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy

The code below:

```
function lookForMatches()
{
    for (var a=1;a<=2000;a++)
    {
        for (var b=1;b<=a;b++)
        {
            c=a*a*a+b*b*b;
            d=5*c*c;
            e=d-4;
            f=d+4;
            g=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(e))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(e))
            h=Math.floor(Math.sqrt(f))*Math.floor(Math.sqrt(f))
            if (g==e||h==f)
                document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML+=c+" ";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML+="Done."
}
```

is supposed to check for Fibonacci numbers in the sequence of the sums of positive cubes, but the output is:

> 2 5075441272 2976917960 7114243176 Done.

I ran the Fibonacci test manually in Windows Calculator, and although the square root of (5*5075441272<sup>2</sup>±4) is extremely close to an integer value, it's definitely *not* an integer! I'm not even certain if the number 5075441272 is actually a valid sum of cubes. How large can integer values be in Javascript without introducing roundoff error?

Comment: In JavaScript, all numbers are `double`s (double-precision binary floating-point numbers). It has 53 bits of precision.

Comment: what do you mean by round-off for an integer? round to what?

Comment: @ChristianFritz In JavaScript there are no true int values. All numbers are type Number, so some sort of internal rounding must be occurring.

Comment: @michael_n Largest value error-free is not the same as max value. SO NOT A DUPLICATE!

Comment: Get values by Number.MAX_VALUE  http://jsfiddle.net/7z68q/

Comment: @Samuel Number.MAX_VALUE returns 1.7976931348623157e+308 so it's not useful to me.

Comment: @michael_n I was mistaken. I guess my question is a duplicate after all.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Sorry, I put your name on the comment about the "duplicate" controversy by mistake, so please disregard it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max size is +/- 9007199254740992

[ECMA SPEC](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)

Also it appears that this has been answered here as well  : 
[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t)

Comment: That explains the error I experienced!

Comment: New output: `2 Done.`